# Slow camera and app close within less than minute

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm developing an android application which detect text using OpenCV's MSER algorithm. The application is working just fine and doing what it should do, but it closes after less than 1 minute! note that there is no errors or something. I think the problem is with the memory, I monitored the memory of my device while the application was running and there was memory left in my device still it stop working and return me to my phone's home page and close the music if I'm listening to something. I think that the application is very heavy and doing so much work that why the camera became slow and it close suddenly.

I don't know how to solve this problem.. can someone tell me how to solve this?

My code:

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.lama.myapplication.MainActivity">



<org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/java_camera_view"
    />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

java class:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {


private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
JavaCameraView javaCameraView;
Mat mRgba;
//imgGray, imgCanny;
private Mat mGrey,mIntermediateMat;


BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch(status){
            case BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS:{
                javaCameraView.enableView();
                break;
            }
            default:{
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

static {

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    //camera permission
    String[] perms = {"android.permission.CAMERA"};
    int permsRequestCode = 200;
    requestPermissions(perms, permsRequestCode);

    javaCameraView=(JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.java_camera_view);
    javaCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    javaCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);


}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if (javaCameraView!=null)
        javaCameraView.disableView();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    if (javaCameraView!=null)
        javaCameraView.disableView();
    System.gc();

}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()){
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV not loaded");
        mLoaderCallBack.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);

    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV loaded");
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_9,this,mLoaderCallBack);
    }
}

/**
 * A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
 * which is packaged with this application.
 */
public native String stringFromJNI();

// Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
static {
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    /*mRgba=new Mat(height,width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    imgGray=new Mat(height,width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    imgCanny=new Mat(height,width, CvType.CV_8UC1);*/
    mIntermediateMat = new Mat();
    mGrey = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    mRgba.release();
}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    //  mRgba=inputFrame.rgba();

   /* Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba,imgGray,Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
   return imgGray;

    Imgproc.Canny(imgGray,imgCanny, 50,150);
    return imgCanny;*/

    // return mRgba;

    mGrey = inputFrame.gray();
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

    detectText();
    return mRgba;
}

private void detectText() {
    Scalar CONTOUR_COLOR = new Scalar(255);
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoint = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    List<KeyPoint> listpoint;
    KeyPoint kpoint;
    Mat mask = Mat.zeros(mGrey.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    int rectanx1;
    int rectany1;
    int rectanx2;
    int rectany2;
    int imgsize = mGrey.height() * mGrey.width();
    Scalar zeos = new Scalar(0, 0, 0);

    List<MatOfPoint> contour2 = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    Mat kernel = new Mat(1, 50, CvType.CV_8UC1, Scalar.all(255));
    Mat morbyte = new Mat();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();



    Rect rectan3;
    //
    FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.MSER);
    detector.detect(mGrey, keypoint);
    listpoint = keypoint.toList();
    //
    for (int ind = 0; ind < listpoint.size(); ind++) {
        kpoint = listpoint.get(ind);
        rectanx1 = (int) (kpoint.pt.x - 0.5 * kpoint.size);
        rectany1 = (int) (kpoint.pt.y - 0.5 * kpoint.size);
        rectanx2 = (int) (kpoint.size);
        rectany2 = (int) (kpoint.size);
        if (rectanx1 <= 0)
            rectanx1 = 1;
        if (rectany1 <= 0)
            rectany1 = 1;
        if ((rectanx1 + rectanx2) > mGrey.width())
            rectanx2 = mGrey.width() - rectanx1;
        if ((rectany1 + rectany2) > mGrey.height())
            rectany2 = mGrey.height() - rectany1;
        Rect rectant = new Rect(rectanx1, rectany1, rectanx2, rectany2);
        try {
            Mat roi = new Mat(mask, rectant);
            roi.setTo(CONTOUR_COLOR);
            roi.release();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("mylog", "mat roi error " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    Imgproc.morphologyEx(mask, morbyte, Imgproc.MORPH_DILATE, kernel);
    Imgproc.findContours(morbyte, contour2, hierarchy,
            Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    for (int ind = 0; ind < contour2.size(); ind++) {
        // rectan3 = Imgproc.boundingRect(contour2.get(ind));
        rectan3 = Imgproc.boundingRect(contour2.get(ind));
        if (rectan3.area() > 0.5 * imgsize || rectan3.area() < 100
                || rectan3.width / rectan3.height < 2) {
            Mat roi = new Mat(morbyte, rectan3);
            roi.setTo(zeos);

        } else
            Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba, rectan3.br(), rectan3.tl(), CONTOUR_COLOR);
    }

}


//camera permission cont.
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){
    switch(permsRequestCode){
        case 200:
            boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            break;
    }
}


}
```

Can someone tell me how can I optimize my application and solve this problem?

**EDIT:**
I tried to release all of the Mat objects as follow:

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    if(mRgba != null){
        mRgba.release();
    }

    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba().clone();

    mGrey = inputFrame.gray();
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

    detectText();
    return mRgba;

}

private void detectText() {
    Scalar CONTOUR_COLOR = new Scalar(255);
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoint = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    List<KeyPoint> listpoint;
    KeyPoint kpoint;
    Mat mask = Mat.zeros(mGrey.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    int rectanx1;
    int rectany1;
    int rectanx2;
    int rectany2;
    int imgsize = mGrey.height() * mGrey.width();
    Scalar zeos = new Scalar(0, 0, 0);

    List<MatOfPoint> contour2 = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    Mat kernel = new Mat(1, 50, CvType.CV_8UC1, Scalar.all(255));
    Mat morbyte = new Mat();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();


    Rect rectan3;
    //
    FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.MSER);
    detector.detect(mGrey, keypoint);
    listpoint = keypoint.toList();
    //
    for (int ind = 0; ind < listpoint.size(); ind++) {
        kpoint = listpoint.get(ind);
        rectanx1 = (int) (kpoint.pt.x - 0.5 * kpoint.size);
        rectany1 = (int) (kpoint.pt.y - 0.5 * kpoint.size);
        rectanx2 = (int) (kpoint.size);
        rectany2 = (int) (kpoint.size);
        if (rectanx1 <= 0)
            rectanx1 = 1;
        if (rectany1 <= 0)
            rectany1 = 1;
        if ((rectanx1 + rectanx2) > mGrey.width())
            rectanx2 = mGrey.width() - rectanx1;
        if ((rectany1 + rectany2) > mGrey.height())
            rectany2 = mGrey.height() - rectany1;
        Rect rectant = new Rect(rectanx1, rectany1, rectanx2, rectany2);
        try {
            Mat roi = new Mat(mask, rectant);
            roi.setTo(CONTOUR_COLOR);
            roi.release();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("mylog", "mat roi error " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    Imgproc.morphologyEx(mask, morbyte, Imgproc.MORPH_DILATE, kernel);
    Imgproc.findContours(morbyte, contour2, hierarchy,
            Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    for (int ind = 0; ind < contour2.size(); ind++) {
        // rectan3 = Imgproc.boundingRect(contour2.get(ind));
        rectan3 = Imgproc.boundingRect(contour2.get(ind));
        if (rectan3.area() > 0.5 * imgsize || rectan3.area() < 100
                || rectan3.width / rectan3.height < 2) {
            Mat roi = new Mat(morbyte, rectan3);
            roi.setTo(zeos);
            roi.release();
        } else
            Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba, rectan3.br(), rectan3.tl(), CONTOUR_COLOR);
    }

    mask.release();
    kernel.release();
    morbyte.release();
    hierarchy.release();
    mGrey.release();
    mIntermediateMat.release();

}
```

Yet still I'm having the same problem!
Can someone please help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Application close because of memory issue.

1. First, you have to release all allocated Mat object at the end of your function ** detectText() **
2. for the function onCameraFrame(...) release the Memory before reallocation it.

Example you can try

```
 @Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(final CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    if(mRgba != null){
        mRgba.release();
    }

    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba().clone();

   //your code here
}
```

//EDIT : 12/04/2017

Your code should be

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) 
{
if(mRgba != null){
    mRgba.release();
}

 if(mGrey != null){
    mGrey.release();
}

mRgba = inputFrame.rgba().clone();
mGrey = inputFrame.gray().clone();

detectText();
return mRgba;

}

private void detectText() {
Scalar CONTOUR_COLOR = new Scalar(255);
MatOfKeyPoint keypoint = new MatOfKeyPoint();
List<KeyPoint> listpoint;
KeyPoint kpoint;
Mat mask = Mat.zeros(mGrey.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
int rectanx1;
int rectany1;
int rectanx2;
int rectany2;
int imgsize = mGrey.height() * mGrey.width();
Scalar zeos = new Scalar(0, 0, 0);

List<MatOfPoint> contour2 = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
Mat kernel = new Mat(1, 50, CvType.CV_8UC1, Scalar.all(255));
Mat morbyte = new Mat();
Mat hierarchy = new Mat();


Rect rectan3;
//
FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.MSER);
detector.detect(mGrey, keypoint);
listpoint = keypoint.toList();
//
for (int ind = 0; ind < listpoint.size(); ind++) {
    kpoint = listpoint.get(ind);
    rectanx1 = (int) (kpoint.pt.x - 0.5 * kpoint.size);
    rectany1 = (int) (kpoint.pt.y - 0.5 * kpoint.size);
    rectanx2 = (int) (kpoint.size);
    rectany2 = (int) (kpoint.size);
    if (rectanx1 <= 0)
        rectanx1 = 1;
    if (rectany1 <= 0)
        rectany1 = 1;
    if ((rectanx1 + rectanx2) > mGrey.width())
        rectanx2 = mGrey.width() - rectanx1;
    if ((rectany1 + rectany2) > mGrey.height())
        rectany2 = mGrey.height() - rectany1;
    Rect rectant = new Rect(rectanx1, rectany1, rectanx2, rectany2);
    try {
        Mat roi = new Mat(mask, rectant);
        roi.setTo(CONTOUR_COLOR);
        roi.release();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d("mylog", "mat roi error " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

Imgproc.morphologyEx(mask, morbyte, Imgproc.MORPH_DILATE, kernel);
Imgproc.findContours(morbyte, contour2, hierarchy,
        Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
for (int ind = 0; ind < contour2.size(); ind++) {
    // rectan3 = Imgproc.boundingRect(contour2.get(ind));
    rectan3 = Imgproc.boundingRect(contour2.get(ind));
    if (rectan3.area() > 0.5 * imgsize || rectan3.area() < 100
            || rectan3.width / rectan3.height < 2) {
        Mat roi = new Mat(morbyte, rectan3);
        roi.setTo(zeos);
        roi.release();
    } else
        Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba, rectan3.br(), rectan3.tl(), CONTOUR_COLOR);
}

mask.release();
kernel.release();
morbyte.release();
hierarchy.release();
mIntermediateMat.release();

}
```

Comment: can you please post the whole code where shall I release each mat, please? because I tried it and got a black screen, so if you please can post the whole code of the detectText method with the mat releases please?

Comment: See my updated post, I released all of the mat objects as you suggested but still same problem appears :(

Comment: Same problem :(

Comment: Any other suggestion?

Comment: I have tried copy pasting this solution but still, the app closes and the camera preview is slow.